# WPF: Designer failing to add third party control. This is causing the designer to restart

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to gain designer support for control from the Extended WPF Toolkit. I have referenced the assemblies and added the controls to the Toolbox.

Attempting to add any of the controls to the designer fails with

> A reference to "Xceed.Wpf.Tookit, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4" has been added to the project. In
>   order to use types from the new reference, press OK to restart the
>   XAML Designer.

Once the restart is complete attempting to add the control again triggers the same error.

What I have tried:

Unblocking the assembly, adding and removing references, adding controls programatically (which works), adding the correct xmlns, making references unversioned.

Adding a reference via Nuget and then navigating to the packages folder and attempting to add controls to the toolbox from the assemblies there results in the same issue.

I am pretty much out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating assembly binding failures using "fuslogvw.exe" I discovered the xaml designer process was logging failues resolving references to the assembly.

Adding the Xceed.Wpf.Tookit.dll to the GAC using gacutil.exe solved the issue.

```
gacutil.exe -i "Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll"
```

Comment: The proper answer!

Answer (score 3):

Add the extended WPF tool kit via the Nuget Package Manager.

Comment: Adding a reference via Nuget and then navigating to the packages folder and attempting to add controls to the toolbox from the assemblies there results in the same issue.

Comment: This can be a solution from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

My symptoms were the same, but the cause was different, so I'll add an additional answer.

The package in the toolbox was from the dll in "Program Files" while the ones that got added to the project were from the GAC. To resolve, you can add the packages from PF to the project, or the reverse, from the GAC to the toolbox.